# how does Tracker.autorun pick out its computation?

Tags: meteor

Looking at [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#tracker_autorun), this mostly works magically...but I'd like to know how it decides which variables are going to form the dependency for the computation. It picks out only "reactive" vars, for example the following:

```
  window.bar = 1
  Tracker.autorun (c) =>
    bar = window.bar
    foo = Session.get('foo')
    console.log('autorun', foo, bar)
```

If I change the value of `Session.set('foo')` this will cause the computation to run again.
whereas just changing `window.bar` doesn't cause a rerun. If I use a subscribe result (not a collection) this also works, so that I guess is reactive too.

Are there any guides to understanding this behavior a bit better?

### EDIT:

thanks for the comments below that clarify the computation is able to be inferred because accessors are used for reactive vars, so meteor can track deps.

However I need a bit more clarity to understand when a var is flagged. for instance in this example below, the `subscribe` call is outside the `autorun`, but it puts the results into an array. So that means that Tracker is not just tracking calls to (reactive var) accessor methods, but also any variables that are referenced within a block - even if the calls to setup those methods are outside the `autorun()` block.

```
  subList = [
    Meteor.subscribe("Players"),
    Meteor.subscribe("Stuff" )
  ]

  Tracker.autorun (c) =>
    subReady = _.filter subList, (item) ->
      return item.ready()
    allDone = (subList.length == subReady.length)
    # this code will rerun when the subs ready() are true
```

maybe i should add this as a new question... it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353852/meteor-client-async-pattern-how-to-implement-a-waiton-for-a-list-of-subscripti/26358443#26358443) .

Comment: `Meteor.subscribe` returns a handle to the subscription. That handle has a method called `ready`. That method is a reactive data source (as you can read in the documentation), so in your autorun, it is the calls to the `ready` method that is reactive, not your `Meteor.subscribe` calls. Tips: use `_.every` in your autorun instead of your solution.

Comment: that's clear, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert and haven't read much about it, but I can try to explain it briefly.

---

All reactive variables have a thing called a dependency. For example, when one creates a new `ReactiveVar`, an new dependency is created. [See here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-var/reactive-var.js#L44).

To retrieve the value from a reactive variable, one must call a function. In that "getter", the dependency is instructed to remember that it has a dependency. For example, [see here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-var/reactive-var.js#L64) for `ReactiveVar.get`.

To change the value for a reactive variable, one must call a function. In that "setter", the dependency is notified that something has changed, and that signals that all functions depending on the dependency must rerun. For example, [see here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-var/reactive-var.js#L82) for `ReactiveVar.set`.

---

Not complicated, right? Well, that was just the easy part, all that remains now is building the infrastructure that makes it work :) That's harder and more complicated to explain.

Reactive variables aren't reactive by themselves; they must be evaluated in a reactive environment in order to be reactive. A reactive environment is created by calling `Tracker.autorun`. [See here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/tracker/tracker.js#L438).

When you call `Tracker.autorun`, the function you passed to it will be executed in a new reactive environment, and all dependencies the reactive variables notifies of with the `depend` method will be tracked by the environment. When you call `aDependency.depend`, [this function](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/tracker/tracker.js#L317) will be executed, and it kind of adds the dependency to the environments list over dependencies it depends on.

When a reactive variable changes its value, [this function](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/tracker/tracker.js#L342) will be executed. It tells the environment that one of the reactive variables it depends on has changed, and invalidates all the dependencies in the environment. After this has happened, the entire function you passed to `Tracker.autorun` will be re-run, and the new dependencies will be tracked.

Do you get the big picture? It's implementation is a bit more complicated than I've explained, but I think that's kind of how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that whenever you access a reactive variable, it's through a function call, like `Session.get(...)`, or `collection.find(...).fetch()`, or `Meteor.status()`. A function like `Session.get` does not only get the value of a Session variable, but also registers a dependency on the current computation (the current computation is dynamically scoped, so `Session.get` knows that it was called from an autorun).

Here's how you can implement your own reactive variable using `Tracker.Dependency`:

```coffee
dependency = new Tracker.Dependency()
currentValue = null

@setCurrentValue = (newValue) ->
  if newValue isnt currentValue
    # rerun computations which depend on this Dependency
    dependency.changed()

    currentValue = newValue

@getCurrentValue = ->
  # register this dependency on the current computation (if there is one)
  dependency.depend()

  return currentValue
```

And here's how you could use it:

```coffee
setCurrentValue("hello")
Tracker.autorun ->
  console.log(getCurrentValue())
# => "hello" printed

setCurrentValue("goodbye") # => "goodbye" printed
```

For more information, you could look at this guide: https://meteor.hackpad.com/DRAFT-Understanding-Deps-aAXG6T9lkf6 (note that Tracker was originally called Deps in older versions of Meteor)